# Next js override main div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am learning  React and using Next js as a framework.

My project structure simply follow the tutorial and using next-sass with next.config.js

```
//-- next.config.js
module.exports = withSass({
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
  }
})
```

What I want is to remove the default margin on all corners of the page. Suppose I want to cover the whole page with #F5F5F5. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Use the inspector to see which element is adding the margin, then add a CSS rule selecting that element and setting the margin to 0.

Comment: @Mjuice I tried to do that but I can't find ways to override the outer div since its not the div which I declared, its the div where the next js put any component I made I think. Any Ideas on how to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do two things:

1. If this is to be applied to every page, you'll want to make [a custom App file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), so that you don't have to manually import your main `.scss` into each page. (**important**: read the note in the link above about defining `getInitialProps` within the `_app.js` file)
2. Create a `.scss` file that targets the `body` element. By default, it has a `margin: 8px;` style applied to it -- you'll want to override this. Then `import` this `.scss` file into the `_app.js` file.

**Working codesandbox**:

[image: Edit NextJS Sass Example]

---

**pages/_app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import "../styles/index.scss";

class MyApp extends App {
  // remove this 'getInitialProps' if you don't plan on render blocking
  // for example, signing a user in before the requested page is loaded
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    return {
      pageProps: {
        ...(Component.getInitialProps
          ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
          : {})
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

**styles/index.scss**

```
$foreground: #007ec5;
$background: #ebebeb;

body {
  background: $background;
  color: $foreground;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```